# Can't get SPI working in nucleo stm32f446re and SD card

Tags: stm32, sd-card, spi, nucleo

I am trying to communicate a nucleo stm32f446re with an SD card module.

I am using SPI1, and I have configured PA4 to be CS with GPIO.

This is the code:

### port_sd.c

```c
SPI_HandleTypeDef hspi = {
        .Instance = SPI1,
        .Init = {   .Mode = SPI_MODE_MASTER,
                    .Direction = SPI_DIRECTION_2LINES,
                    .DataSize = SPI_DATASIZE_8BIT,
                    .CLKPolarity = SPI_POLARITY_LOW,
                    .CLKPhase = SPI_PHASE_1EDGE,
                    .NSS = SPI_NSS_SOFT,
                    .BaudRatePrescaler = SPI_BAUDRATEPRESCALER_256,
                    .FirstBit = SPI_FIRSTBIT_MSB,
                    .TIMode = SPI_TIMODE_DISABLE,
                    .CRCCalculation = SPI_CRCCALCULATION_DISABLE,
                    .CRCPolynomial = 0x00000001},
        .pTxBuffPtr = (uint8_t *)SPI_REG_TXFIFO,
        .TxXferSize = 1,
        .TxXferCount =0,
        .pRxBuffPtr = (uint8_t *)SPI_REG_RXFIFO,
        .RxXferSize = 1,
        .RxXferCount =0,
        .RxISR = 0,  
        .TxISR = 0,  
        .hdmatx = 0,  
        .hdmarx = 0,
        .Lock = HAL_UNLOCKED,
        .State = HAL_SPI_STATE_READY,
        .ErrorCode = HAL_OK
    };

size_t port_sd_init()
{
    __GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();

    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;

    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_5 | GPIO_PIN_6 | GPIO_PIN_7;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_PULLUP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_HIGH;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF5_SPI1; //AF5 para pines SPI1

    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin  = GPIO_PIN_4;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    //HAL_SPI_RegisterCallback(&hspi,HAL_SPI_MSPINIT_CB_ID,My_SPI_MspInit);
    RCC->APB2ENR |= RCC_APB2ENR_SPI1EN;
    HAL_SPI_Init(&hspi);
    SPI1 -> CR2 |= SPI_CR2_SSOE;

    return 0;
}

HAL_StatusTypeDef port_sd_transmit(uint8_t *pData, uint16_t Size, uint32_t Timeout){
    return HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi, pData, Size, Timeout);
}

HAL_StatusTypeDef port_sd_receive(uint8_t *pData, uint16_t Size, uint32_t Timeout){
    uint8_t dummy[1];
    dummy[0] = 0xFF;
    return HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive(&hspi, dummy, pData, Size, Timeout);
}
```

### sd.c

```c
uint32_t volatile * spi = (void *)0;

static inline uint8_t spi_xfer(uint8_t d) 
    uint8_t tx_data[1];
    tx_data[0] = d;
    uint8_t rx_data[1];
    REG32(spi, SPI_REG_TXFIFO) = d;
    int i = 8;

    port_sd_transmit(tx_data,1,100);
    do {
        port_sd_receive(rx_data,1,100);
        i--;
    } while ((rx_data[0] & 0b1111110) && i > 0);

    return rx_data[0];
}

static inline uint8_t sd_dummy(void) 
{
    return spi_xfer(0xFF);
}

static uint8_t sd_cmd(uint8_t cmd, uint32_t arg, uint8_t crc) 
{
    unsigned long n;
    uint8_t r;
        
    sd_dummy();

    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_4, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    uint8_t reg[6];
    reg[0] = cmd;
    reg[1] = arg >> 24;
    reg[2] = arg >> 16;
    reg[3] = arg >> 8;
    reg[4] = arg;
    reg[5] = crc;
    if(port_sd_transmit(reg,6,1000) != HAL_OK)
    {
        printf("Error de tx");
    }

    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_4, GPIO_PIN_SET);


    n = 1000;
    do {
        r = sd_dummy();
        if (!(r & 0x80)) {
            goto done;
        }
    } while (--n > 0);
    kputs("sd_cmd: timeout");
done:
    return r;
}

static inline void sd_cmd_end(void)
{
    sd_dummy();
}

static void sd_poweron(unsigned int input_clk_khz)
{
    long i;
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_4, GPIO_PIN_SET);
    
    for (i = 10; i > 0; i--) {
        sd_dummy();
    }
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_4, GPIO_PIN_SET);
    sd_dummy();
}

static int sd_cmd0(void)
{
    int rc;
    dputs("CMD0");
    rc = (sd_cmd(0x40, 0, 0x95) != 0x01); 
    sd_cmd_end();
    return rc;
}

static int sd_cmd8(void)
{
    int rc;
    dputs("CMD8");
    rc = (sd_cmd(0x48, 0x000001AA, 0x87) != 0x01); 
    sd_dummy(); /* command version; reserved */
    sd_dummy(); /* reserved */
    rc |= ((sd_dummy() & 0xF) != 0x1); /* voltage */
    rc |= (sd_dummy() != 0xAA); /* check pattern */
    sd_cmd_end();
    return rc;
}

static void sd_cmd55(void)
{
    sd_cmd(0x77, 0, 0x65); 
    sd_cmd_end();
}

static int sd_acmd41(void)
{
    uint8_t r;
    dputs("ACMD41");
    do {
        sd_cmd55(); 
        r = sd_cmd(0x69, 0x40000000, 0x77); /* HCS = 1 */
    } while (r == 0x01); 
    return (r != 0x00);
}

static int sd_cmd58(void)
{
    int rc;
    dputs("CMD58");
    rc = (sd_cmd(0x7A, 0, 0xFD) != 0x00); 
    rc |= ((sd_dummy() & 0x80) != 0x80); /* Power up status */
    sd_dummy();
    sd_dummy();
    sd_dummy();
    sd_cmd_end();
    return rc;
}

static int sd_cmd16(void)
{
    int rc;
    dputs("CMD16");
    rc = (sd_cmd(0x50, 0x200, 0x15) != 0x00);
    sd_cmd_end();
    return rc;
}

static uint16_t crc16(uint16_t crc, uint8_t data) {      //CRC16 XMODEM
    crc = (uint8_t)(crc >> 8) | (crc << 8);
    crc ^= data;
    crc ^= (uint8_t)(crc >> 4) & 0xf;
    crc ^= crc << 12;
    crc ^= (crc & 0xff) << 5;
    return crc;
}

#define SPIN_SHIFT  6
#define SPIN_UPDATE(i)  (!((i) & ((1 << SPIN_SHIFT)-1)))
#define SPIN_INDEX(i)   (((i) >> SPIN_SHIFT) & 0x3)

static const char spinner[] = { '-', '/', '|', '\\' };

static uint8_t crc7(uint8_t prev, uint8_t in)
{
  // CRC-7 polynomial 0x89
  uint8_t remainder = prev & in;
  remainder ^= (remainder >> 4) ^ (remainder >> 7);
  remainder ^= remainder << 4;
  return remainder & 0x7f;
}

int sd_init(unsigned int input_clk_khz)
{
  kputs("INIT");
    sd_poweron(input_clk_khz);
    if (sd_cmd0() || // software reset SD
        sd_cmd8() || // check version of SD card
        sd_acmd41() || // start SD initialization process
        sd_cmd58() || //reads the OCR register of the SD (voltage range, UHS-II status, Card capacity status, Card power up status)
        sd_cmd16()) { //set block length to 512B
        kputs("ERROR");
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

### main.c

```c
int main()
{
    HAL_Init();

    port_sd_init();
    
    sd_init(HSI_VALUE);
    while(1){

    }
    return 0;
}
```

I have checked MOSI and CS and they seem to be working correcly.

The problem is that SCK seems to never activate so MISO does not return anything.

### EDIT

This are the registers after configuration:

### GPIOA

[MODER](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLukW.png)

[PUPDR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3uWSj.png)

[IDR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LExQL.png)

[ODR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Tq9G.png)

[AFRL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVEsG.png)

### SPI1 REGISTERS

[CRI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sA2oa.png)

[CR2, SR, DR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdPRY.png)

Comment: Write a simple test program where you set the SCK pin to GPIO Output and toggle it "manually" to check for bad solder joints/shorts/any other electrical problems. If that works and SPI does not work, read out and check/post GPIOA registers content.

Comment: I have checked in a test and the GPIO PA5 which is the SCK pin I'm using works fine as a GPIO output. The SCK pin keeps the same. I have included in the post the registers.

Comment: Registers content looks OK. GPIOA_IDR indicates that PA5 is 1, if this is after SPI_CR1.SPE=1, given CPOL=0 it means something holds the pin up externally. Try in this state i.e. SPI enabled, manually in debugger change GPIOA_MODER so that PA5 is output and, again manually in debugger using GPIOA_ODR, toggle.

Comment: One more thing - I am not familiar with SD cards, but I assumed clock is input to them. Is this always true?

Comment: I will try to change PA5. Also, SD cards have SPI bus mode, so they need MOSI, MISO, CS and SCK from master (which is the nucleo board). Edit: I think it is now working as I am getting response from SD card. I nedd to check the transmittions later as I don't have an oscilloscope now. Thanks!!